# How to get min and max date and time using one column in mysqli?

Tags: mysqli

table:

```
+---------+--------------------+
|EnNo     |DateTinme           |
+---------+--------------------+
|1        |2017-01-03 10:30:22 |
|1        |2017-01-03 16:41:22 |
|1        |2017-01-03 16:41:22 |
|1        |2017-01-04 10:42:39 |
|1        |2017-01-04 17:42:39 |
+---------+--------------------+
```

I have a table where I have column EnNo and another is DateTime where I have different time on same date. Now I want to get Entrance and Exit time using single column and output look like as shown below. How can I get this output through query.

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|EnNo     |Entrance            |Exit                |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|1        |2017-01-03 10:30:22 |2017-01-03 16:41:22 |
|1        |2017-01-04 10:42:39 |2017-01-04 17:42:39 |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Which showing wrong data. So, How can I fix this ?Please help me.

Comment: It isn't clear how you define the logic for arriving at the various starting and ending points.

Comment: actually I have single column i.e DateTime Now I want to compare first date to second date make a table in format of entrance and exit as I have mention in my second table @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: This comment does not make your question any clearer.

Comment: can any body help me please ? :(

Answer (score -1):

select *
from attandance  t
where EnNo = (select t1.EnNo
            from attandance  t1
            order by t1.DATETIME desc
            limit 1
           )
OR EnNo= (select t1.EnNo
            from attandance  t1
            order by t1.DATETIME
            limit 1
           );